# What browser plugins (ActiveX, or those for Chrome/Firefox/Safari etc) pose the most risk for your company?

Tags: appsec, web-browser, activex

I'm looking for a list of risky browser plugins that we should prevent their use on the desktop.

It's probably safe to assume that old versions of Flash are on the list, but what versions?  What other objects should we check for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All plugins. :/

With that being said, I don't think you can practically blacklist plugins.  You should really do it on a case by case basis and whitelist them.  That way whenever someone askes for one to be installed, you have a record, and can keep track of them to keep them up to date with the latest patches.

Answer (score 2):

On the subject of Flash plugins, pretty much the only way to get the most secure version is to block all older than current (as Flash tends to have security patches in every update) - the practicality of this may well depend on your particular environment, however; if you are happy to pop up a "you need the most recent version" message for your users then definitely do this.